# Интересная галерея с кареткой

Tags: javascript, html, css3, html5, modx

Нашел интересную галерею.
[image: До ::ховера]
[image: Во время ::ховера]

Вопрос: Как можно сверстать такого рода галерею, где все изображения были бы попарны с минимальным количеством блоков (Причем каретку посередине можно двигать влево - вправо)

Или может есть  плагины, с помощью которых можно реализовать такое?

Спасибо )

Comment: [ссылка на плагин](http://topdevs.net/before-after-viewer/)

Comment: ну это плагин для wp, я не юзаю его, но хотелось бы использовать подобный слайдер (обычно использую modx как cms)